# .htaccess domain.com/blog to mirror blog.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get my domain.com/blog to mirror the contents of blog.domain.com

So, if I make the request domain.com/blog/article1, it'll display the contents of blog.domain.com/article1

Any help is appreciated :)

***Progress so far***
If I place the following two lines into my .htaccess file, I can mirror the entire domain to blog.domain.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Mirroring is unlikely to be a good idea. You should have one canonical location and one canonical location only. Why do you want it thus?

Comment: If you're moving from one place to another, you should make it a redirect (external) rather than a rewrite (internal); you can add to the rule flags `[R=301]`

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Thanks for the tips. I'm just experimenting with possibilities at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [P,L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @amine, I added in a third line, to make http://domain.com/blog (without the trailing /) also mirror.
**RewriteRule ^blog$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [P,L,NC,QSA]**